# AVX2: How to move a single element from vector to vector

Tags: sse, simd, neon, avx, avx2

The problem is:

```
a1[7] = b[6];
a1[15] = b[14];
a2[7] = b[0];
a2[15] = b[8];
```

All three vectors are `uint8x16_t`

On `aarch64` NEON, it would be rather trivial:

```
mov a1.b[7], b.b[6]
mov a1.b[15], b.b[14]
mov a2.b[7], b.b[0]
mov a2.b[15], b.b[8]
```

How can I do this on AVX2?

I already loaded the vectors accordingly into `__m256i a, b;` where `b` contains the same 128bit vector twice, and then:

```
        const __m256i shuffle=_mm256_set_epi64x(0x0808080808080808, 0x0000000000000000, \
                                                0x0e0e0e0e0e0e0e0e, 0x0606060606060606);
        const __m256i mask=_mm256_set1_epi64x(0x8000000000000000);
        .
        .
        .
        b = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(b, shuffle);
        a = _mm256_blendv_epi8(a, b, mask);
```

Yes, it works the way I want, but I cannot get rid of the feeling that it's anything else than optimal, sacrificing two registers for this kind of trivial operations.

Am I missing something? Are there more efficient ways dealing with this problem?

Shall I modify this to a 64-bit shift then blend? That would need the same number of registers and instructions. Any suggestions?

Pleas note that I cannot overwrite other lanes in `a`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the types of `a1`, `a2`, and `b` in your example? I think you should state more clearly what you'd like to accomplish.

Comment: Oops, they are unsigned bytes. I'll edit my question accordingly.

Comment: If possible use an immediate blend (like `vpblendw`), but that only works with word or larger elements.  (And `vpblendd` is more efficient).  byte-shuffle + byte-blend is your only option; just be glad you don't need to move bytes between 128b lanes; then you'd need vinserti128 or vextracti128.  (Or `vperm2i128`).  BTW, in AVX terminology, a "lane" is 128 bits.  "elements" are what you're calling "lanes".  So it's a confusing question title for non NEON people. >.<  Similarly, sometimes youcan use an immediate shuffle (like `vpshufd` or `vpslldq`, or a 64-bit element-wise shift, or `vpshuflw`)

Comment: For just a single byte, it might be worth it to `vpextrb` to an integer register and `vpinsrb` into another vector.  That's still 2 uops for each instruction (one of them a shuffle uop), but you avoid needing the vector constants.  If you're doing a lot of moving a couple bytes at a time between vectors, your algorithm is really not SIMD-friendly...  If I have time later, I'll write this up as an answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks. The problem above is just a small portion of a very large function, and definitely the least SIMD-friendly part, and that has been boggling me the whole time even on NEON. But trust me, it cannot be helped since it's quite a delicate one. Sometimes sacrifices have to be made. I'm considering using `_mm256_sllv_epi64` aka `vpsllvq` instead of the shuffle because of the pipeline dependency.

Comment: Just had another idea: store 256b to an aligned buffer and use `vpinsrb` from memory as needed.  Only 2 uops per insert + 1 for the store.  Store-forwarding latency ~= 7 cycles (+1 for the insert shuffle), vs. 2 or 3 each way for ALU (to/from GP registers).

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the suggestion, but I unrolled the loop so deep that I do it eight times consecutively, and thus, initializing two registers for sixteen operations total isn't that much of a waste. And besides, I'm trying to keep the memory I/O at its minimum for multicore computing even if it results in an increase in number of instructions executed.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE: `vpshufb` + `vpblendvb` is 3 total uops on Haswell/Skylake, so it's by far your best option when you can keep vector constants in registers across multiple operations.  (Fun fact: SSE `pblendvb` is only 1 uop on Skylake, but 4-operand `vpblendvb` is 2).  But store/reload to a temporary on the stack barely adds anything to memory bandwidth requirements; store/reload latency doesn't depend on an L1D hit (it forwards from the store buffer), and per-core private L1/L2 are write-back caches, so frequently-dirtied stack cache lines are rarely written to L3/DRAM.